# XSL output method text including whitespaces in xsl

Tags: xslt, text, methods, whitespace

I am creating some xsl to transform my xml into text (which will be csv eventually).  I am using VS2008.  When I use the editor to create the xsl, the transformed output is indented as per my xsl.  However, if I edit the xsl and remove the formatted whitespaces it outputs correctly - but doing it like this is a nightmare to work with.

Is there some xsl pre-processor commands or markup I can put in to prevent this?  I want to ignore any whitespace in my xsl and only output text using `<!CDATA[]]>` or `<xsl:text>`.

My XSL is as below - this indents the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <!-- @* is all class attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>CSV Output</xsl:text>
    <!-- Start of output -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//rows/row">
      <![CDATA[row id=]]><xsl:value-of select="(@id)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- OK, that is the end of the file -->
    <![CDATA[<EOF>]]>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
CSV Output
      row id=0
      row id=1
    <EOF>
```

However, the following outputs correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <!-- @* is all class attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>CSV Output</xsl:text>
    <!-- Start of output -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//rows/row">
<![CDATA[row id=]]><xsl:value-of select="(@id)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
<!-- OK, that is the end of the file -->
<![CDATA[<EOF>]]>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is output correctly as follows:

```
CSV Output
row id=0
row id=1
<EOF>
```

I also want to control where a new line is included.  In my xsl I am not telling it to include one.

Please help!!

Thanks,

Andez

Comment: JFTR, you do not have to put a simple attribute selector in parentheses. See also the example that I added to user357812's (the accepted) answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XSLT processor strips white-space text nodes in the template only between XSLT elements.

So, in

```
<xsl:for-each select="//rows/row"> 
  <![CDATA[row id=]]><xsl:value-of select="(@id)"/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

the `xsl:for-each` element has two white-space text child nodes: One after `xsl:value-of`, which is stripped; the other before the CDATA section, which is not stripped.

Bottom line: Use `xsl:text` elements.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//rows/row"> 
  <xsl:text><![CDATA[row id=]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: The bit about the XLST processor stipping white-space text between XSLT elements was the missing piece of the puzzle for me. Thank!

Comment: Tip for [LibXML2](http://xmlsoft.org/) users (PHP, Python, browsers, etc.): if you not use `<xsl:text>` it not strip spaces (!).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`xsl:strip`](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_preserve-space.asp) element to declare which elements should not have whitespace (or use `*` for all elements):

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

The counter part is `xsl:preserve`, which allows you to declare which elements should have whitespace preserved. You could use both:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="td span"/>
<!-- strip spaces from all elements apart from td and span elements -->
```

Comment: When I use the < xsl: strip-space elements =" *"/> it still outputs the CDATA <EOF> with a tab...  Any ideas?  I have put the strip-space elements = "*" at the top of my file under xsl:output method = "text"

Comment: OK - I've removed the CDATA and replaced with the xsl text and it is fine

Comment: Tip for [LibXML2](http://xmlsoft.org/) users (PHP, Python, browsers, etc.): if you not use `<xsl:text>` it not strip spaces (!).